# Delete rows in a range using vim

Tags: vim

I've got a large text file (+100k long rows)  that I've been using vim to edit, I would like to remove rows in a given range i.e do something like delete rows 500 to 50000 are there any commands to do this?

Comment: I love vim. but if the deletion is single operation you want to do on the big file, I would use shell tools to kick it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Almost every editing command can have range specified in form

```
:<from>,<to><CMD>
```

so what you want is probably:

```
:500,50000d
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this in your vim session:

```
:500,50000d
```